# Is there a word for "becomes empty"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

After running a certain operation a value is taken from field A to field B. After the operation field A is empty. Is there a word or better phrase for this?

> During the operation field A _________ [*becomes empty*].

Comment: Empties is a word which means becomes empty.

Comment: This sounds like it's at least somewhat technical, so there may be a better word or phrase relevant to the specific context. For example, if you're talking about a database, it makes more sense to say that the field becomes "null" rather than becomes "empty"; if you're talking about Java, "empty" only really makes sense when talking about a collection; etc.

Comment: _Empty_ is one of the words that has a stative adjective form (_The pot is empty_), an inchoative verbal form (_That pot empties fast_), and a causative verbal form (_He emptied that pot slowly_) that all have the same shape. Unlike, for instance, _full_, which is only an adjective, but has related inchoative (_The pot filled_) and causative (_He filled the pot_).  Or _dead_, which has a related inchoative _die_, and an unrelated causative _kill_. Zero derivation is quite common.

Comment: Since you're talking about a move, the contents of A become **undefined**, because there's still something in it, even if only random bits.  It's not empty in the sense that a bottle can be empty of, e.g., beer.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are talking about a computer function here... given the wide range of answers it may mean your question is too broad.

Comment: @DRF Though either I believe works gramatically, I would use "empties" only in a transitive manner. "The drain empties the bathtub."

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Andrew Leach is right in saying *is emptied* is better than *empties* here.

However, for your particular example, I’d suggest:

> During the operation field a **is cleared.**

When relating to GUIs, it’s a much more common way of expressing that the content has been removed from an input field.

Comment: For additional support on the fact that 'clear' is the best fit for talking about GUI's, Google 'clear a field' and 'empty a field'. You'll find that 'clear a field' returns more results that are programming-related, and that the first SO result for 'empty a field' has a top, accepted answer that uses the verb 'clear' instead of 'empty'. Clear is definitely the word when talking about GUI in a programming context. (SO question reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236332/jquery-how-to-empty-input-field)

Comment: I would have used _"is reset"_. Still not one word though.

Comment: cant "clears" be used the same way as empties?

Comment: @MrLister *Reset* carries a slightly different meaning though. If the field has a non-blank/non-null default value, I would take *reset* to mean that this default value was restored. Whereas *clear* always means that the field is made blank/null, aka *empty*.

Comment: Notice that the *absolutely* best approach would be to "Avoid passive voice" and write: **"This operation clears field A."**

Answer (score 23):

The verb *empty* can be transitive or intransitive.

> [with object] Remove all the contents of (a container)
>   [no object] (of a place) be vacated by people in it
>
> [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/empty)]

Thus, the field ***empties.***

Usually, though, where something happens as a result of something else (like a value being taken from a place), the action of an agent is implied by using the passive voice, *is emptied.*

Answer (score 10):

Another word when used as a verb may be,

[**Drain**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drain)

> - 1.1 - Cause or allow (liquid) to run off or out of something.
> - 2.1 - Cause (a valuable resource) to be lost or used up.

- Example 1: The pond was *drained* of all the water.
- Example 2: The thief was caught *draining* all the funds from my
  account.
- Example 3: Playing football *drains* my energy quickly.

Comment: In the question though, it is not a liquid or resource that is being removed.

Answer (score 7):

How about *depleted*?

> During the operation field A is **depleted**.

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deplete):

1. to empty of a principal substance. *The lake was **depleted** of water. **Depleting** the country of its natural resources.*
2. to lessen markedly in quantity, content, power, or value. ***Deplete*** our life savings. Their **depleted** resources.

Comment: It is vanishingly rare to hear about a character array or string which becomes empty to be said to be "depleted of characters".  Anyway "is depleted" is two words. "becomes empty" is already two words.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a computer operation.

Depending on the type of variable, one possibility might be **`nullify`**. This wouldn't apply to scalar fields (which can't be set to null).

Per
https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=nullify:

> 1. To make null; invalidate.

Answer (score 3):

The word [*vacate*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vacate) could also work, in the form *is vacated*:

> During the operation field A **is vacated**.

Answer (score 3):

If it is computer-related, one other option for a GUI field is *blanked*.

Comment: We are looking for answers that provide some context on why they are correct ideally with citations. As is stands, this answer may be removed.

Comment: This answer shouldn't be removed, it's got the important fact that this is computing jargon, not everyday English, and in that specialist domain this is common knowledge. Do you really want extracts from (say) the PostgreSQL documentation? Two similar jargon terms are **voided** and **nulled**. The differences are most important to a programmer. A non-programmer (i.e. "user") quite likely  won't understand any differences and a programmer will need to know precisely what context (programming language or system) the terms relate to.

Comment: "is blanked" is two words, just like the original "becomes empty". You can rescue this usage by swiching to active voice: *the field blanks*.  The verb *to blank* works as an intransitive. It is reasonably clear that this means that the field spontaneously lapses to a blank value.  Switch to this and you have a winner here.

Comment: @Kaz I see you make the same remark on multiple answers and while I understand why you're doing it, the fact is that OP has accepted an answer that also consists of two words. Furthermore, in the computer GUI sense I'm talking about, the verb is always used passively since the software behind it is doing the blanking, not the field itself.

Comment: @Falc In fact, the original "becomes empty" is perfectly sensible.

Answer (score 2):

> During the operation field A *was voided*.

At [Oxford Dictionaries’ online site we read for *void*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/void):

> 2. Discharge or drain away (water, gases, etc.) ‘the gases are usually voided into the mechanism’ More example sentences
>
>    2.2 usually as adjective voided Empty or evacuate (a container or space) ‘a fully voided core assembly’

Answer (score 0):

> During the operation field a becomes **diminished**.

or

> During the operation field a **diminishes**.

This is simply a synonym for empty, like Andrew Leach already said, the word empty can be used as both a transitive and intransitive verb so you would be fine to say:

> During the operation field a **empties**. (intransitive)

or

> During the operation field a **empties itself**. (transitive)

Comment: Your example sentences suggest that field A gets smaller. This in no way implies that there was something in field A, and now there is not.

Comment: That's if your speaking in a purely literal sense, but perhaps the OP may be looking for a slightly metaphorical usage which can be applied to a broader scenario.

Comment: I don't agree that 'diminished' is a synonym for 'empty' - in fact, in this context I would understand this to mean that the diminished value was less, or smaller, but not nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a computer operation.

Depending on the context, one possibility is **`initialized`**. This is typically used when the value of a variable is set to an initial value in order to be [ready for use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251791.aspx), especially the case with object variables for which existing state is cleared in the process of preparing for new use.

From the original question, it seems like some sort of move operation is taking place, which is typically not a single operation in a computer sense. Such an operation would typically involve a copy of a value from field A to B, then a modification of state of field A. These steps might be encapsulated within a function. Thus the way that the 'emptying' takes place is specific to the implementation of the function, and the data type of variable whose state is being modified. I.e. the meaning of 'empty' is semantic.

Per
https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=initialized:

> 1. To set (a starting value of a variable).

Comment: this would only apply if emptiness were the initial value, which it may or may not have been. Assuming it was, then "re-initialize" would be more appropriate, but if the initial value was not empty, this wouldn't be right at all

Answer (score 0):

> During the operaion, field A is **invalidated**

This is an indicator that the previous value no longer applies, and was "blanked out" for being obsolete.

Comment: This is a technical term, not jargon.  Nonetheless, it may be too specific for your needs.

Comment: "is invalidated" is two words; OP already has two words, namely "becomes empty", and is looking for one word.  The verb *to invalidate* introduces unwanted interpretations; it has connotations of a value becoming not valid. Perhaps a blank value is perfectly valid.

Comment: I would understand this to mean that field A's value is no longer valid (for whatever reason), but not that the value is changed or removed. As a contrived example, if B was a choice between "Shape or Colour", and A had a value of "Round", changing B to "Colour" would _invalidate_ the value of "Round".

Comment: OP specifically asked for a word *or phrase*.   I assumed he was looking for the best way to express the concept, not a compact way.

Answer (score -1):

In comments, John Lawler wrote something that is important enough that it should be searchable here, so I am installing it as a "Community Wiki" answer:

> *Empty* is one of the words that has a stative adjective form (*The pot is empty*), an inchoative verbal form (*That pot empties fast*), and a causative verbal form (*He emptied that pot slowly*) that all have the same shape. Unlike, for instance, *full*, which is only an adjective, but has related inchoative (*The pot filled*) and causative (*He filled the pot*).  Or *dead*, which has a related inchoative *die*, and an unrelated causative *kill*. Zero derivation is quite common.

Answer (score -2):

The sentence may be written as:

> During the operation field A is unoccupied.

or it may be like this:

> During the operation field A is exhausted.

or

> During the operation field A is expended.